# JS Global Hit Count

Tags: javascript, hitcounter

I've built a pretty simple novelty page that just calls a basic javascript function when a button is clicked, but I want to be able to count how many times that button has been clicked, globally.
Being relatively new to javascript I'm struggling to think of how to solve this. If you can help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Globally as in any user? You need a serverside language.

Comment: An example of that would be php or coldfusion.  I would go with php.

Comment: @epascarello or alternatively localStorage if it's per computer (and the computer has localStorage support).

Comment: if you don't have a server, you can upload the clicks to a google spreadsheet using the form rest api by hiding the emedded form and making the button a submit.

Comment: What about google analytics and track events?

Comment: @markcial: good point if the count need not be displayed on the page. If that's the case, then you could use a hidden iframe and make the button/link hit a special page on the server to create identifiable http logs entries without even using JS...

Comment: @markcial I'm using GA already to track page views and the like, can I set it to record a custom variable like js function calls?

Comment: you can use javascript api for google analytics reports api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=visitor&jump=ga_visitors but i recommend you a simpler solution, that is... too much